# How to add label or text in to CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, core-text, cashapelayer

Here is my class and it'll draw a circle, it looks like this:

[image]

```
    class OvalLayer: CAShapeLayer {

    let animationDuration: CFTimeInterval = 0.3

    override init() {
        super.init()
        fillColor = Colors.green.CGColor
        path = ovalPathSmall.CGPath
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    var ovalPathStart: UIBezierPath {
        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0))

        return path
    }
}
```

Now I need to add a text to middle of this circle, I tried to find it on google but nothing that works fine. I am not sure if it's possible or not, can anyone help me if it's possible?

Comment: Have you had a look at `CATextLayer`? https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATextLayer_class/index.html

Comment: yes, I tried out, I couldn't able to find how to add sublayer of CATextLayer to CAShapeLayer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you should add `CATextLayer` as a sublayer to `CALayer`... That works fine that way: try adding `CAShapeLayer` first, and then `CATextLayer` (to same `CALayer` parent layer), for example in following order...

```
// assume self - is UIView instance

self.layer.addSublayer(shapedLayer) // shapedLayer - CAShapeLayer instance
self.layer.addSublayer(textLayer) // textLayer - CATextLayer instance
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, I tried this out, nothing appears, can you more describe place ?

Comment: @roledeneJKS: Can you please comment how did this answer work for you?

Comment: @roledeneJKS: you have to set frame for textLayer before add it

Comment: It'd be great if you showed how to create textLayer

Answer (score 6):

Swift 3.0

```
let label = UILabel()
label.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 12)
label.frame = CGRect(x: OvalLayer.frame.origin.x + (circleWidth/2), y: OvalLayer.frame.origin.y, width: OvalLayer.bounds.width, height: OvalLayer.bounds.height)
label.text = "Hello"
label.textColor = UIColor.red
label.isHidden = false

OvalLayer.addSublayer(label.layer)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The text never appears (Swift 4 / XCode 9)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to get the center of your `UIBezierPath` and add a label or a `CATextLayer` to your current layer.

```
let center : CGPoint = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(ovalPathStart.bounds), y: CGRectGetMidX(ovalPathStart.bounds))
```

Now, create a `UILabel` or `CATextLayer` and set the center.

Comment: I'm able to create a CATextLayer but not move it.  I've tried changing bounds, frame, position, etc and it just sits in the top left corner of the layer to which I added it....it refuses to move over my graphic.  How do you move the CATextLayer over a Bezier path?

Comment: same issue with me @Dewey

Answer (score 2):

Text on CAShapeLayer Using CATextLayer

Here i am create CAShapeLayer object and  i am adding CATextLayer to CAShapeLayer
   Here numberOfArcsCount means some 8

```
            CAShapeLayer *progressLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
            [progressLayer setPath:bezierPath.CGPath];


            CATextLayer* text = [CATextLayer new];
            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfArcs.count; i++) {
            text.string =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i];
            text.font = (__bridge CFTypeRef _Nullable)([UIFont fontWithName:@"akaChen" size:42]);
            text.font = (__bridge CFTypeRef _Nullable)([UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]);
            text.fontSize=25;
            text.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,40,40);
            text.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(progressLayer.frame) ,CGRectGetMidY(progressLayer.frame) );

            CGFloat vert = CGRectGetMidY(progressLayer.frame) / CGRectGetHeight(text.frame);

            text.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, vert );
            text.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
            text.foregroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];

           [progressLayer addSublayer:text];
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This way to add label to layer :

**labelFrame** - CGRect

**someString** - String

**layer** - your layer

```
        let label = CATextLayer()
        label.frame = labelFarme
        label.string = someString
        layer.addSublayer(label)
```